# twisted handle_quit() the way to disconnect?

Tags: python, logging, twisted

so I'm implementing a log server with twisted (python-loggingserver) and I added simple authentication to the server. If the authentication fails, I wanna close the connection to the client. The class in the log server code already has a function called handle_quit(). Is that the right way to close the connection? Here's a code snippet:

```
if password != log_password:
    self._logger.warning("Authentication failed. Connection closed.")
    self.handle_quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `handle_quit` message you're referring to is [this one](http://code.google.com/p/python-loggingserver/source/browse/trunk/loggingprotocol.py#107), then that should work fine.  The only thing the method does is `self.transport.loseConnection()`, which closes the connection.  You could also just do `self.transport.loseConnection()` yourself, which will accomplish the same thing (since it is, of course, the same thing).  I would select between these two options by thinking about whether failed authentication should *just* close the connection or if it should always be treated the same way a quit command is treated.  In the current code this makes no difference, but you might imagine the quit command having extra processing at some future point (cleaning up some resources or something).